# Show the department number and the lowest salary of the department with the highest average salary

Tags: oracle, max, average, min

Show the department number and the lowest salary of the department with the highest average salary (use subquery). I want check my answer
[image]

Is this correct answer?

```
select min_sal, deptno, round(avg_sal)
from 
(select avg(sal) as avg_sal,
min(sal) as min_sal, deptno
from emp
group by deptno) 
where avg_sal=(select max(avg(sal)) from emp group by deptno);
```

Comment: As you've shared the data as a screenshot rather than text, and not given the output, it would be hard for us to reproduce and test.  As to correctness, does it give the output you expect?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, this is the *standard* EMP table in Scott's schema which exists in Oracle database since dark ages, so - anyone who works with Oracle knows it. But yes, for the rest of **you** :), everything you said makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your query returns (to me, result seems to be OK - as far as I understood the question):

```
SQL> select min_sal, deptno, round(avg_sal)
  2  from (select avg(sal) as avg_sal, min(sal) as min_sal, deptno
  3        from emp
  4        group by deptno
  5       )
  6  where avg_sal = (select max(avg(sal)) from emp group by deptno);

   MIN_SAL     DEPTNO ROUND(AVG_SAL)
---------- ---------- --------------
      1300         10           2917
```

However, consider a slightly different approach - the one that selects from the `emp` table only once so - if it were a really large table (with many, many rows), such an approach should perform better.

Basically, sort rows by average salaries in descending order and return the one that ranks as the highest:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno,
  3         min(sal) min_sal,
  4         round(avg(sal)) avg_sal,
  5         dense_rank() over (order by avg(sal) desc) rnk_avg_sal
  6     from emp
  7     group by deptno
  8    )
  9  select a.min_sal, a.deptno, a.avg_sal
 10  from temp a
 11  where a.rnk_avg_sal = 1;

   MIN_SAL     DEPTNO    AVG_SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      1300         10       2917

SQL>
```